# In Entity Framework, why isn't lazy loading working for a one-to-zero-or-one navigation property?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, lazy-loading, entity-framework-6

Consider `Person` and `Address` classes defined as

```
class Person
{
  public int PersonId { get; set; }
  public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}

class Address
{
  public int PersonId { get; set; }
  public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

where only some Persons have an Address, but all Addresses have a Person. This is a [one-to-zero-or-one relationship](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620#RequiredToOptional), so I configure it as

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Address>()
  .HasKey(a => a.PersonId)
  .HasRequired(a => a.Person)
  .WithOptional(a => a.Address);
```

Now, in my code the following approach (eager loading) works perfectly fine.

```
var person = context.Person
  .Include(a => a.Address)
  .Single(a => a.PersonId == 123);
var address = person.Address; // address != null (correct)
```

However, the following approach (lazy loading) does not.

```
var person = context.Person
  .Single(a => a.PersonId == 123);
var address = person.Address; // address == null (incorrect)
```

Moreover, I hooked up SQL Profiler and I can see that EF isn't even attempting to lazy load the Address in the second case--it just returns null.

I've been unable to locate any documentation that says EF does not lazy load one-to-zero-or-one navigation properties. Is this by design, is it a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

I tested this with both Entity Framework 5 and Entity Framework 6 Alpha 3 and obtained the same results.

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure `ProxyCreationEnabled` and `LazyLoadingEnabled` are true for the context?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I figured this one out. The entity classes must be declared as `public` and the properties `public virtual` for lazy loading to work. I.e.

```
public class Person
{
  public int PersonId { get; set; }
  public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
  public int PersonId { get; set; }
  public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I also came upon this problem. Did you manage find any documentation on this?

Comment: No, unfortunately I did not. I figured it out through trial and error.

Comment: This is somewhat obvious because of the dynamic proxy stuff, but I didn't notice it also and had to search for it. Thanks to your answer here, it is working now ;)

Comment: "The entity classes must be declared as `public` [...] for lazy loading to work." has just cost me around 5 hours debugging. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Another point that might also be the reason sometimes, is if one forgets to add the virtual modifier to the navigation property

Answer (score 1):

There are some some Rules to enable or have lazy loading:

```
context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled should be true.
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled should be true.
```

Navigation property should be defined as public, virtual.

Context will not do lazy loading if the property is not defined as virtual.

**Example**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext() : base("ProjectConnection")
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
    }

}
```

[read more](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/lazyloading-in-entity-framework.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Database first approach, make sure that Lazy Loading Enabled property is True. You can find this property in the properties of the EDMX diagram.

You can also override the behavior by setting 
`dbcontext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true`
where dbcontext is the instance of DbContext.